# Variables in mootools dollar sign element calls

Tags: javascript, mootools, dollar-sign

So I have an element I want to modify (with Fx.Tween, but I suppose it doesn't really matter). However, the element id is dynamically generated, meaning I have to piece it together from some variables.

So let's say... (in js)

```
name = 'foo';
id = '42';
```

and I want to access element `$('foo_42')`... how would I type it out?

$(name+'_'+id) doesn't seem to work, unless I'm doing it wrong...?

Actual example from my code:

```
var highlight = new Fx.Tween($(accountID+'_'+type+'_'+permission), {
    background-color: #f00;
});
```

**Update**: Looks like this question had no answer - my JS in the code sample is just wrong... due to incorrect usage of the Fx.Tween function. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's pretty much exactly it. Mootools won't know if you do `$('foo_42')` or `$('foo' + '_' + '42')`, all it will see is `foo_42`. Just make sure that ID actually exists. If it doesn't, then `$()` will return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
var highlight = new Fx.Tween($(accountID+'_'+type+'_'+permission), {
    background-color: '#f00'
    //                ^^^^^^
});
```

? The original code you posted isn't valid Javascript. Note that the JS object syntax is not CSS.

The syntax `$(name+'_'+id)` must work as long as `name` and `id` are defined in that scope.